# If $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $2$, then what can be the order of center of $G$?

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $2$, then what can be the order of center of $G$ ?

a.  $0$

b.  $1
$

c.  an even integer $≥ 2$

d. an odd integer $≥3$

Since $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, normalizer of $H$, $N(H) = G$
and center of $G$, $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $N(H)$.

These facts do not lead to any result. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H=\{e,h\}$. Since  $H $ is normal and only has two elements, we have $$ghg^{-1}=h\iff gh=hg,\; \forall g\in G.$$ Hence  $h \in Z(G).$ Also note that the order of  $h $ is $2$. Hence  $Z(G) $ contains even number of elements(by Lagrange's) including  $e $ and  $h $.